# Dynamodb query from multiple keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm relatively new to dynamodb, i'm trying to create a social media app using was dynamodb. I have a user followers table that looks like the below schema.

[image]

And this is how my posts table look like

**Posts API**
[image]

I am seeking a method to retrieve all posts created by followers of a specific user from the DynamoDB database. My initial plan was to first query the followers table to obtain a list of user IDs for the followers and then use those keys to query the posts table. However, I have been unable to determine a way to effectively query a table with a list of keys using DynamoDB. Additionally, I require the retrieved posts to be sorted by date and the querying process to support pagination through the use of LastEvaluatedKey, ExclusiveStartKey, and PageCount. Is it possible to accomplish this efficiently and with good performance using DynamoDB, or should I consider revising my data model?

(I am using nodejs)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: sorry @ErmiyaEskandary, it's not an image of a code it's my database model displayed In NoSQL workbench. this is more of a concepts and theory-related question.

Comment: [Table markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) is supported on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks i'll update it

Comment: Best practice for dynamodb is generally [single table design](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/). You have modeled 2 different tables with a relationship to each other. This is a common design for traditional RDBMS, but not so much for dynamodb. Dynamodb is about designing for your intended access patterns, so that your data can be queried in as few calls as possible.

Comment: thanks for the comment @jordanm i understand what you are saying but even with single table design how can I get posts of followers of particular user ? it should be really helpful if you can explain or point out any examples of how to achieve this. thanks again,

Comment: Single table design is not a best practice. Use single table design when it makes sense to do so, if it can provide more efficiency while not making your schema more complex for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to create a schema for DynamoDB

1. Define your access patterns, list them out in order of priority
2. View other models/schemas which are similar online
3. Use a tool like [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) to create sample models with the ability to visualize
4. Iterate continuously, make necessary changes to the schema when you spot something that will make your schema more efficient/performant.

#### Your Schema

You have given a single access pattern:

> I am seeking a method to retrieve all posts created by followers of a specific user from the DynamoDB database

##### Users

| pk | sk | followers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | USER#user1 | [user2, user4, user99] |
| user2 | USER#user2 | [user6, user4, user99] |

##### Posts

| pk | sk | post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user2 | COMMENT#00001#DATE | some comment |
| user2 | COMMENT#00002#DATE | some comment |
| user2 | COMMENT#00003#DATE | some comment |
| user2 | REPLY#00001#DATE | some reply |
| user2 | POST#00001#DATE | some post |
| user2 | POST#00002#DATE | some post |
| user99 | COMMENT#00001#DATE | some comment |
| user99 | COMMENT#00002#DATE | some comment |
| user99 | COMMENT#00003#DATE | some comment |
| user99 | REPLY#00001#DATE | some reply |

#### Your access pattern

- `GetItem` for user `user1`
- Parse list of followers
- Run a `Query` for each `userId` returned from above and state that `sk` begins_with `POST`
- You will be returned each users post in order by date

##### Pseudo

```
SELECT followers FROM Users WHERE pk = 'user1' AND sk='USER#user1'
```

```
FOR user in followers:
    SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE pk = user AND sk BEGINS_WITH 'POST'
```

#### Single Table Design

You could model both tables in a single table, but it doesn't provide much benefits other than having a single table to manage:

| pk | sk | post | followers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | USER#user1 |  | [user2, user4, user99] |
| user2 | COMMENT#00001#DATE | some comment |  |
| user2 | COMMENT#00002#DATE | some comment |  |
| user2 | COMMENT#00003#DATE | some comment |  |
| user2 | REPLY#00001#DATE | some reply |  |

---

#### Summary

I don't particularly like this format, if it were my application I would model it something similar to the [DynamoDB Forum Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.CreateTables.html#SampleData.CreateTables2).